# Can compression of folder be undone when it comes to slow?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, compression

I know that compressing save disk space on my hard drive and I know that it is mutch slower for read a file. However I will compress the `C:\Users` folder. Personal files are stored on a SSD drive.

Before I do it, I'll know if this can be undone when I find when it comes to slow. So my question is can I undone compression for folders and if yes, how could I do it?

[image: Here is an image for more information.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could do that by uncheck the same checkbox and click OK. This will return you to the basic properties for the folder.